# Input[type='file'] label name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to modify the look of an input[type='file'] element which I have done,

```
<div class="own_image_wrapper">
  <%= f.label :image, id: 'own-image-label', class: 'lato-font fileContainer image_button' do %>
  Choose Your Own
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fileContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.fileContainer input[type='file'] {
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
  font-size: 999px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  top: 0;
}

.image_button{
  padding:15px;
  color:$white;
  background:$blue;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

The next stage for me is to change the label text once a user selects a file, my first issue is that the event doesn't always fire, leaving a button with no content.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
// Update Choose your own image label with file name
$( '#own-image-label [type=file]' ).on( 'click', function (){
  var $input = $( this );

  setTimeout( function (){
     $input.parent().text( $input.val().replace(/([^\\]*\\)*/,'') )
   }, 0 )
  } );

});
```

and when it does fire I can't click the input any more as the following has been removed from the DOM:

```
<input id="campaign_image" type="file" name="campaign[image]">
```

and secondly how can I stop the input type['file'] from being removed from the DOM?

### Edit

This is the markup before

```
<label id="own-image-label" class="lato-font fileContainer image_button" for="campaign_image">
  Choose Your Own
  <input id="campaign_image" type="file" name="campaign[image]">
</label>
```

And then if I select a file called myfile.jpg this is the markup

```
<label id="own-image-label" class="lato-font fileContainer image_button" for="campaign_image">myfile.jpg</label>
```

Comment: Could you post the rendered markup? Also, the DOM needs to be ready at the time you're attaching the handler

Comment: @billyonecan i have updated the question with the markup as requested, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the text of the `label`, it overwrites its current contents. You need to target the text node itself, and set the value of that:

```
this.parentNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue = $input.val().replace(/([^\\]*\\)*/,'');
```

You must ensure that the DOM is ready before you attempt to attach the handler, otherwise it may not be attached. Also, it doesn't look to me like your `setTimeout()` serves any purpose. If you don't need it for any specific reason, you can remove it.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WKLv7/2/)

Comment: thank you, that explains a lot, though now if i change the image selected the previous filename is still set as the text..what could I do to listen for a new event?

Comment: @Richlewis Bind a change handler instead of a click handler. That way the event will fire after the input's value has been updated - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/WKLv7/4/)